# Can asterisk monitor() and mixmonitor() applications be executed on same channel?

Tags: asterisk

Im recording calls with Mixmonitor() application, it works fine, but recently i had a request to record each leg of call with addition to mixedfile. I know, that i can record each leg of call with Monitor() and then use external script tp mix it, but the problem is that it is additional loading of server. So I wonder can I do it by means of asterisk? For example by using Monitor and Mixmonitor together?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the call-legs with MixMonitor's parameters:

```
MixMonitor(mixed.wav,r(in.wav)t(out.wav))
```

as stated in the description:

```
asterisk*CLI> core show application MixMonitor

r(file): Use the specified file to record the *receive* audio feed.
Like with the basic filename argument, if an absolute path isn't given,
it will create the file in the configured monitoring directory.

t(file): Use the specified file to record the *transmit* audio feed.
Like with the basic filename argument, if an absolute path isn't given,
it will create the file in the configured monitoring directory.
```